# Converting a maven project to clojure project on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, clojure, functional-programming

I am  new to clojure and want to use eclipse as the ide for clojure proramming. I have installed counterclockwise plugin in eclipse. I have to create a maven project and then convert it to a clojure project. After creating the maven project, I am trying to convert it to a clojure project by using the Configure option that comes on right clicking the project name. But it is saying "Error while trying to toggle clojure language support for the project. Problems encountered while setting project description."
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This is an interesting question but Eclipse AFAIK is... probably not a great choice for clojure. Pretty much every clojure programmer is going to use Emacs/Cursive(IntelliJ)/Atom, in roughly descending order of popularity (modulo a few vim hold-outs). Now watch all of the Eclipse-loving Clojurists come out of the woodwork to bash me.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to create a maven project and then convert it to a clojure project

I don't think you **need** to do that, and that could be connected to the issue you are having. Have you tried to create a [new Clojure project as described in the documentation?](https://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html#create-new-project) ... also, it seems [you can enable extra logging to understand what's going on](https://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html#_activate_tracing) when you use the plugin.

Finally, [it seems that Counterclockwise is not under active development anymore (last commit on March 2017)](https://github.com/ccw-ide/ccw) so I'd suggest looking into [other IDEs/editors](https://www.clojurenewbieguide.com/) or be aware that you might hit a few blockers with CCW.